# Question edit by anonymous user

Tags: discussion, review

There was [a review](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23488) for a suggested edit by an anonymous user. To me it seems like the OP was editing after a logout due to the writing style, so I approved it.

While I wonder a bit that anonymous users can edit at all, I wonder even more that they can edit the question. I could understand that it's allowed by someone passing by to edit an answer, mostly because I'd sometimes want to do that on Internet forums as well. In case of Stack Overflow such an anonymous answer edit could improve the quality.

Is there any evidence that OP edited his own question or should that edit be rolled back (if it gets approved at all)?

Comment: When in doubt about that, you can always flag it for a mod (or ask one of us in chat) – as we have other means of verification. The edit you're referring to seems to have a 20:80 chance having been from a different user: I agree with your suspicion, though, that it was the same user.

Comment: @Izzy What other means?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Mod powers :) Not sure if we (mods) should list them in public. We don't want to help the spammers to better camouflage, do we?